# How to add class on hovering element in MooTools?

Tags: mootools, addclass

I am using MooTools **1.12**

How to ad a class to an a element on hover?

e.g.

I have this

```
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
```

anf when hovering overr a link I want this:

```
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
<a class="hover" href="example.html">Some text</a> <!-- I am over this link -->
<a href="example.html">Some text</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Simply define an event which adds or remove the class on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$$('a').addEvents({
  'mouseenter': function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
  'mouseleave': function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
});
```

However, if you are using this to change CSS properties on link, you are better off using the `:hover` pseudo-class in CSS. Using the pseudo-class will enable your changes to work on browsers without Javascript.

Comment: no need for $(this), just `this.addClass('hover');` and `this.removeClass('hover');` should be fine.

Comment: @eerne: Depending on the version of MooTools and the browser used, `this` might not be prototyped with the MooTools functions. It's simply safer to use `$(this)` and it doesn't negatively affect the performance of the script.

Comment: it does affect performance somewhat, particularly on a mouseover/out event, which can be triggered multiple times in quick succession. in this instance, `this` will be prototyped for certain - `$$("a")` returns els and sets the prototypes (for IE6-8)